# Heads-up Notification - Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

I'm trying to show a notification-type heads-up but I could not. What I tried

```
final Notification.Builder notif = new Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
    .setContentText(getString(R.string.text))
//  .setTicker(getString(R.string.tick)) removed, seems to not show at all
//  .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) removed, match default
//  .setContentIntent(contentIntent) removed, I don't neet it
    .setColor(Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.yellow))) //ok
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small) //ok
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
//  .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_CALL) does not seem to make a difference
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX); //does not seem to make a difference
//  .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE); //does not seem to make a difference

mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notif.build());
```

The notification is shown only as an icon in the bar.
I'm using API 21 on API 21 emulator (not L preview)
I have tried:
`android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar`,
`android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`
and `NotificationCompat.Builder`

SDK examples are not available. does anyone know how to do it?

**I made it working by adding:**

```
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
```

is this the best way?

Comment: if this worked for you , then ou should add it as an answer.

Comment: Please note, heads-up notifications can be EXTREMELY annoying while watching media or using any app -- not surprisingly, almost every app uses the top of the screen. They cast a shadow over the top third of the screen (tested on my 8" Tegra Shield). If you MUST use these (heaven knows why), at least make disabling them within your app an option, please!

Comment: @user1499731 Android has native support for disabling notification peeking for an app IIRC.

Comment: setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE) works

Comment: I have posted a brief on showing heads-up notification at 
https://medium.com/@md.noor.asad/heads-up-push-notification-from-rest-and-firebase-when-app-is-in-background-or-foreground-6c4457fb6d4b

Comment: You may also follow my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890459/4932661

Answer (score 87, accepted):

According to [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up), you are required to set a vibrate or ringtone to make Heads-up work. However, here's a quick hack that doesn't require VIBRATE permission to produce a head-up notification:

```
notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
```

EDIT:

Don't abuse heads-up notification. See [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-guidelines) for when to use heads-up notification:

> MAX: For critical and urgent notifications that alert the user to a condition that is time-critical or needs to be resolved before they can continue with a particular task.
>
> HIGH: Primarily for important communication, such as messages or chat events with content that is particularly interesting for the user. High-priority notifications trigger the heads-up notification display.

Comment: This is not true - I recently got a crash report for a SecurityException on a Samsung Android 4 device using this method

Comment: @DaiwikDaarun Is it thrown by `setVibrate`? If it's only reproducible on Android 4.x, we can add a runtime version check.

Answer (score 16):

According to Google:
https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

> If a notification's priority is flagged as High, Max, or full-screen, it gets a heads-up notification.

So the following code should generate an heads-up notification:

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
```

Should be enough. But apparently the .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE) has to be set also. Hopefully Google will fix this in their final release of Android 5.0.

Not sure if bug or feature...

Comment: `Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH` is high enough, you don't have to (and probably shouldn't) set `PRIORITY_MAX` only because you want your notifications to be shown as heads-up.

Comment: It appears that either a sound and/or vibrate has to be set on the notification for it to show as "heads up". This actually makes sense, since it would be strange to see a silent "heads up" notification, and it may not be obvious that it's a system notification otherwise.

Comment: In Android M it's now possible to disable heads up notifications/peeking on a per app basis. So if this peeking disabled, whatever you do, your heads up notifications won't show. Keep this in mind .

Comment: While it is poorly documented, it is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up `The notification has high priority **and** uses ringtones or vibrations`

Answer (score 8):

All my apps doesn´t show the Notification, for example i have a Nexus 6 with Android 5.1.1, but i think this is an issuse since Android 5.0, i had to set:

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
```

Correctly set and manage notification priority

Android supports a priority flag for notifications. This flag allows you to influence where your notification appears, relative to other notifications, and helps ensure that users always see their most important notifications first. You can choose from the following priority levels when posting a notification:

> **MAX** Use for critical and urgent notifications that alert the user to a condition that is time-critical or needs to be resolved before
>   they can continue with a particular task.
>
> **HIGH** Use primarily for important communication, such as message or chat events with content that is particularly interesting for the
>   user. High-priority notifications trigger the heads-up notification
>   display.
>
> **DEFAULT** Use for all notifications that don't fall into any of the other priorities described here and if the application does not
>   prioritize its own notifications
>
> **LOW** Use for notifications that you want the user to be informed about, but that are less urgent. Low-priority notifications tend to
>   show up at the bottom of the list, which makes them a good choice for
>   things like public or undirected social updates: The user has asked to
>   be notified about them, but these notifications should never take
>   precedence over urgent or direct communication.
>
> **MIN** Use for contextual or background information such as weather information or contextual location information. Minimum-priority
>   notifications do not appear in the status bar. The user discovers them
>   on expanding the notification shade.

Answer (score 6):

To set the [priority](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#priority), use the [setPriority](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setPriority(int)) function (introduced in API 16) alongwith [setDefaults](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDefaults(int)) (added in API 11) of [Notification Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html). Choose the priority [DEFAULT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_DEFAULT), HIGH, LOW, MAX, MIN as per the requirement of your app. Defaults can also be chosen [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_ALL).

A small snippet:

```
notification = NotificationBuilder(service)
notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check that your phone is not in “silent” or “do not disturb” mode. I spent day before I found it. I just leave this comment for those who get the same problem and found this question.

Answer (score 1):

Should set high priority and use ringtones or vibrations.

```
notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up

> **Heads-up Notifications**
>
> With Android 5.0 (API level 21), notifications can appear in a small
>   floating window (also called a heads-up notification) when the device
>   is active (that is, the device is unlocked and its screen is on).
>   These notifications appear similar to the compact form of your
>   notification, except that the heads-up notification also shows action
>   buttons. Users can act on, or dismiss, a heads-up notification without
>   leaving the current app.
>
> Examples of conditions that may trigger heads-up notifications
>   include:
>
> - The user's activity is in fullscreen mode (the app uses    fullScreenIntent), or
> - The notification has **high priority** and uses **ringtones or vibrations**

Answer (score 1):

For devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher the notification channel requires high importance

```
new NotificationChannel("ID", "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line in your code to display heads up notification it's only working for Lollipop version**

```
notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set vibrate. You only need to set sound. It's less intrusive. I don't get any sound on mine, but the notification displays on top. Make sure you use PRIORITY_HIGH and DEFAULT_SOUND.

```
 NotificationChannel channel = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_01",
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }


        Notification notification =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "notify_001")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!")
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setChannelId("my_channel_01").build();


        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```