# Heads-up Notification - which side to swipe

Tags: android, heads-up-notifications

I've noticed that apps that use heads-up notifications may have different behaviors. I always swipe my WhatsApp notifications to the left, but my custom SMS app (Textra) notifications must be swiped to the right instead.

I've looked at the documentation of [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) but couldn't find anything related to this. Does anyone know?

As a reference, I found an example of how to implement a heads-up notification on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451893/heads-up-notification-android-lollipop).

**EDIT:** After testing a bit more comparing both apps' heads-up notifications:

- WhatsApp: Can be dismissed swiping left or right, and the notification disappears from the notification bar. If I swipe upwards, it disappears and it keeps the notification on the notification bar.
- Textra: Cannot be dismissed swiping left. Can be dismissed swiping right, but the notification is removed from the bar. Swiping up also dismiss the heads-up and keeps the notification on the bar.