# android gcm push notification playing only sound, not displaying at top

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

On receiving a message from GCM, I'm generating a notification

```
/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
 *
 * @param message GCM message received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_chat)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

The notification is generated, the sound gets played, but it does not get shown at top of screen. The notification is displayed in the quick settings/notifications drop down menu, but at the time when I generate it, it is not displayed at the top of screen, only sound is played.

I want to display it at top of screen when I generate it. How can I do it?

Comment: are you looking for head up notification check this one http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451893/heads-up-notification-android-lollipop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a headsup notification works from android lollipop here you check how to show notification you can see here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html and for headsup you have to set notification priority as below

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
```

**EDIT Nov-17**

**Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH** was deprecated in API level 26. use **IMPORTANCE_HIGH** instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to do

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_icon)
```

Comment: I had already written that in the question, anyways setPriority worked for me

Comment: Just for people who encounter the same issue but different configuration. Probably I should have written it in the comment instead of answer. My bad.