# Android - Notification received but no notification popup (Foreground)

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

My app is receiving the notification correctly but is failing to show a notification pop up with the received info (If the app is opened).

*N.B.: In case if the app is in the background, the notifications are displayed without any issue.*

---

**My Code:**

I receive the notification in this method:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if(remoteMessage!=null)
    {
        String id = null;
        String title = null;
        String body = null;
        String launchPage = null;

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null)
        {
            title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getMessageId()!=null)
        {
            id = remoteMessage.getMessageId();
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "id: " + id);
        Log.i(TAG, "title: "+ title);
        Log.i(TAG, "body: " + body);

        int notif_id = 0;

        sendNotification(notif_id, title, body, launchPage);
    }
}
```

then it calls this one (which is supposed to show the notification as i understand):

```
private void sendNotification(int id, String title, String messageBody, String launchPage)

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
                    .setContentTitle("OMR - "+title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createChannel(notificationManager, CHANNEL_ID);
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Received a notif...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //this line is not showing a notification
    notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

---

Firebase notification

```
{
"data": {
    "message": "data payload only used to force using OnMessageReceived() if in BACKGROUND",
    "notif_id": 1
},
"to" : "e04OAVaRw30:APA91bGyv5_tt4IWRkurjlqkqNlCxTBV8oRne18tQ5puniHPItOMgg11kdt56t5jfZnasb4Ms-tH9xUgWQhHy2eM487llRtlM9_V_PoWJI9KSr6XgCaysiDyS",
"notification": {
    "title": "Notification",
    "body": "This is Notification 2",
    "sound":"default"
}
```

}

---

Result

- the notification is built correctly
- sound played correctly
- notif put in system tray
- **BUT no notification popup appears (i have to show a
  custom dialog for that)**

---

My Problem lies in this specific line

```
notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

which is failing to show the notification

**Update**
i have read more about Android notifications in

> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications

and found out that notifications only show in the notification drawer without popping up (as `Heads-up notifications`).

and according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949501/android-show-notification-with-a-popup-on-top-of-any-application), i can force the notifications to show as Heads-up notifications if i added a high priority to them. Unfortunately this is not working either.

Comment: Are you using FCM ?

Comment: @RahulArora Firebase

Comment: Can post the Payload received from notification?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48918490/app-not-showing-notification-receiving-fcm-when-the-app-is-open
check this link

Comment: @AbidKhan edited the question to include it

Comment: Need `onMessageReceived` code as well. Most probably `sendNotification` isn't getting called due to some condition in `onMessageReceived`.

Comment: Check for Payload and the code in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)`. You might getting a values that doesn't exist in Payload.

Comment: I am not using the data payload at all, and the content is received well in the sendNotification() method

Comment: @Ranjan checked that, its called correctly

Comment: Put a break point on `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` method and debug to see if there is any error.

Comment: In addition to @Shivam Yadav answer,
Remember not to send notification key if you want call in onMessageReceived.

Comment: Please follow these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/a/51501821

Answer (score 7):

[image]

This image explains it all if you are using FCM.

Comment: thank you, ur chart is very enlightening. however, i am using both payloads in the foreground and im having my notif sent to system tray.

Comment: @SoliQuiD Yeah, but you will get the call in onMessageReceived also then it's upto you how do you handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case some of the data I'm passing into the message body is null in the onReceived.

Fixed that and my notification popup was showing again

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
val notificationManager = packageContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```

to

```
val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(packageContext.applicationContext)
```

helps to me