# popup a message when receive message in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android application. In that i have a using Firebase for push notifications. I need to show a popup message in my home page when receive a message in `FirebaseMessagingService` class

**FirebaseMessagingService**

```
String actiondata = remoteMessage.getData().get("action");
if(actiondata.equals("booking")){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.driver.approverequest");
        myIntent.putExtra("contentdata",contentdata);
        myIntent.putExtra("requestid",productId);
        this.sendBroadcast(myIntent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data : athira send " + message);
    }
```

**HomeActivity**

```
 public BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");
        try {
            JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("contentdata"));
            Log.d("hi...........",intent.getExtras().getString("contentdata"));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            StartTrackingDriver();
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.driver.approverequest"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }catch (Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: You need to send only data type notification to get call in your onMessageReceived.

Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54787937/5335382

And then fire a broadcast if home activity is already open else start activity.

Answer (score 0):

register broadcast in `OnCreate()`

```
registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.driver.approverequest"));
```

unregister in `onDestroy()`

```
unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

unregister in onPause will unregister the broadcast whenever your activity goes in background.

**AND**

you're getting string "action" from intent but never set the value to intent.

```
String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");
```

So set the string to intent first.

```
myIntent.putExtra("action",actiondata);
```

**EDIT**
try using `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext)` before `register`, `unregister` & `sendbroadcast()`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.driver.approverequest"));

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(myIntent);
```

Comment: to get "action" from intent, you have to set it first in intent.

Comment: bt it is not getting call inside public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

Answer (score 0):

@Arya
Fcm worked on following concept.

1 App is in front
2 App is in background

1 When app is in front then onReceive method will be called each time irrespective with your json payload that you received from server

2 When your app is in background then onReceive method will be called only when your json does not contain "notification" key. If your payload contain notification key then firebase sdk will manage all.

Answer (score 0):

```
String actiondata = remoteMessage.getData().get("action");
 if(actiondata.equals("booking")){
     Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.driver.approverequest");
     myIntent.putExtra("contentdata",contentdata);
     myIntent.putExtra("requestid",productId);
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(myIntent);
     Log.d(TAG, "Message data : athira send " + message);
 }

//In your HomeActivity
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
  @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String data = intent.getStringExtra("contentdata");
         String id = intent.getStringExtra("requestid");

 //Write your pop up message logic here
  }
     }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("com.driver.approverequest"));
        super.onResume();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {  
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
     super.onPause();
 }
```