# app not receiving FCM notifications when the app is killed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

> W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.flagg327.guicomaipu
>   (has extras) }

It happens when the app is killed from recent apps tray and not receiving 
**FCM** notifications

Comment: Add some code and show the notification sample.

Comment: Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54787937/5335382

Comment: @Veeresh keep your notification in data payload.It work surely.Hope you understand my points.Thanks

Comment: @rehul i tryed that also

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you...
Just Go to Settings and enable autostart permission for your app..

Comment: i givan auto start  permission for app but still not working

Comment: are you getting the data from firebase or not?

Comment: i am getting notfication from firbase only if app is open or its in recent apps in oppo