# How to get consistent heads-up notification behaviour when phone is active?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I've got got the following notification. When receiving a notification while the phone is used, the OS will show a heads-up notification instead of the fullscreen intent. This looks all normal according to the documentation.

But if you swipe up the heads-up notification and receive a new notification right after. The behaviour looks inconsistant. Sometimes the notification opens the fullscreen intent although the phone is still active. Also in some cases i only hear the notification sound without heads-up or fullscreen intent. And sometimes a new heads-up notification is shown.

Is it possible to explain the different behaviour? Or fix it to be more constant (show heads-up when active and otherwise fullscreen intent)? It looks like it's related to the time in between the two notifications.

Implementation:

```
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, ALERT_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert)
    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.alert_notification_title))
    .setContentText(message)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setSound(getDefaultNotificationSound(), AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
    .apply { if (fullscreen) setFullScreenIntent(alertNotificationPendingIntent, true) }
    .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build()

val channel =
        NotificationChannelCompat.Builder(id, NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .setName(context.getString(name))
            .setDescription(context.getString(description))
            .setSound(
                getDefaultNotificationSound(), AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .build()
            )
            .build()

NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).createNotificationChannel(channel)
```

Comment: Are you asking about the [built in rate limiting of heads up notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34537782/1676363)?

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake, that could be the reason. Didn't know about the Rate limiter.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a push notification channel with priority set to `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH` and alter your notification to be sent to that channel

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The channel was already created with a high priority. I will update my question with how i created the channel