# Android show notification content on 6.0 and above

Tags: android

i'm trying to show Notification content as popup on android 5.0 and above, but my coding this feature show only small icon on android status bar and i have to pull down status bar layout to show received notification's content

```
public static void createNotification(Context context, Class activity, String title, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.dollar);
    Notification notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(subject)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setPriority(0)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NOTIFICATIONMANAGER = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NOTIFICATIONMANAGER.notify(159753456, notify);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the priority to high or max in order to trigger a heads-up notification on Android versions that support it:

```
Notification notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    // ...
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
    .build();
```

As stated in the official [Notification documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up) the notification also needs either a vibration or a ringtone to produce a heads-up notification:

> The notification has high priority and uses ringtones or vibrations

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451893/heads-up-notification-android-lollipop) for more information on heads-up notifications.

Comment: unfortunately couldn't resolve problem. i tested that on android 6

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that you need a vibration or a ringtone for it to work!

Comment: No problem ;) Next time try searching for the quesion first, please. Most common questions already have good answers. Thanks!